# FP: How to filter List[A], that way so it will contains all elements except Option[A]

Tags: scala

It is more educational answer, because I have working solution, but I feel that there should be some functional programming pattern or concept that I missed and I want to learn it.

Lets say I have a `List[Player]` where `Player` is the case class. Also I have `Option[Player]` and I want to write method that will return all elements from list except one that (possibly!) contained in `Option`. Here is the code

```
case class Player(id:Long)
val players = List(Player(1), Player(2), Player(3))
var boss = None
def findAllExceptBoss = {
   players.filter(boss != Some(_))
}
findAllExceptBoss.size should be (3)
var boss = Some(Player(1))
findAllExceptBoss.size should be (2)
```

So, my question is - how I can implement `players.filter(boss != Some(_))` in more functional style? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to search the list if the boss is not named, so factor out the search.

```
case class Player(id:Long)
val players = List(Player(1), Player(2), Player(3))
var boss: Option[Player] = None
def findAllExceptBoss = {
   boss match {
     case Some(b) => players.filter(b != _)
     case None => players
   }
}

findAllExceptBoss.size should be (3)
boss = Some(Player(1))
findAllExceptBoss.size should be (2)
```

Comment: Thanks, Bob and guys. There is so much cool suggestions, but I think this is most concise and readable even for newbie, so I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2):

I often find `fold()` to be a handy `Option` unwrapper.

```
boss.fold(players)(b => players.filterNot(_.id == b.id))
```

This way you don't traverse the `players` if you don't have to.

Comment: Thanks, it makes sense. Good optimization

Answer (score 1):

First of all you shouldn't have a var in functional. I would do something like this:

```
def findAllExceptBoss(boss: Option[Player])(players: List[Player]): List[Player] = {
  boss.map(b => players.filter(p => p != b).getOrElse(players)
}
findAllExceptBoss(None)(players).size should be (3)
```

This will also allow you to do something like this:

```
def filterForSpecificBoss = findAllException(boss)
val filtered = filterForSpecificBoss(players)
```

Comment: Unfortunately I need to have boss as "var", because it can be changed during the game. I know about State Monad but I didn't try it yet, because I need more experience in basic Scala

Answer (score 1):

Respecting your method definitions, I'd go for :

```
def findAllExceptBoss= 
         for { 
             p <- players
             b <- boss
             if p != b
            } yield p
```

Comment: Yeah, how I can forgot about for-comprehension:) However to not traverse full list b <- boss should be before p <- players.  Only one thing that disturb me - it is like utility function, is there some general solution(beware of List and Player) like Monad or someth like that..

Comment: The `p<-players` comes first so you get a `List` as a result , otherwise you'll get an `Option` (The first <- determines the result type). For a more general solution, I could think of Monad Transformer, you could then abstract over `Option` and `List`, check for example https://www.scala-exercises.org/cats/monad

Answer (score 1):

The right way to do this is `players.filterNot(boss.toSet)`
Also, don't use `var`s, they are bad.